# opencellid not giving actual location results for blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to get Location of my Blackberry device without using GPS. So, I am using Opencellid for it results. But it is giving me wrong location results.
Can anyone clarify what is the exact procedure and what I might be doing wrong?

My code:

```java
public final static String getQueryString(){
    cellID = Integer.toString(GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getCellId());
    // Retrieves the Location Area Code.
    lac = Integer.toString(GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getLAC());
    // Retrieves the mobile country code.
    mcc = Integer.toHexString(RadioInfo.getMCC(RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkIndex()));
    // Retrieves the Location network Code.
    mnc = Integer.toHexString(RadioInfo.getMNC(RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkIndex()));     
    queryStr="http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?
    key="+myapikey+"&mcc="+mcc+"&mnc="+mnc+"&cellid="+cellID+"&lac="+lac+"&fmt=txt";
    return queryStr;
}

public void httpGetRequest(){
    HttpConnection conn = null;
    InputStream in = null; StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(); String result = "";
    try {
        conn=(HttpConnection) Connector.open(getQueryString()+getString(),Connector.READ);
        conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET); conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-1.0 Confirguration/CLDC-1.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "plain/text");
        in = conn.openInputStream();

        int car;
        while( (car=in.read())!= -1){
            buff.append((char)car);
        }
        in.close();
        conn.close();
        result=buff.toString();

        //get latitude and longitude
        if(result.startsWith("err")){
            System.out.println("Cell not found!");
        }else{
            int pos=result.indexOf(',');
            String lat=result.substring(0,pos);
            int pos2=result.indexOf(',',pos+1);
            String lon=result.substring(pos+1,pos2);
            System.out.println(lat+" "+lon);
            getLocationFromGoogleMaps(lat,lon);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("====Exception: "+ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("====Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to get location from network ?

Comment: What is the error or exception? You might also want to check how to retrieve a location using the built-in LocationProvider in cellsite mode: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/34488/GPS_overview_1679738_11.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this -

```
            try {

                int cellID = GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getCellId();
                int lac = GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getLAC();
                String urlString2 = "http://www.google.com/glm/mmap";
                // Open a connection to Google Maps API 
                ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();                   ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
                connDesc = connFact.getConnection(urlString2);

                HttpConnection httpConn2;
                httpConn2 = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();
                httpConn2.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // Write some custom data to Google Maps API 
                OutputStream outputStream2 = httpConn2.openOutputStream();//getOutputStream();
                WriteDataGoogleMaps(outputStream2, cellID, lac);

                // Get the response  
                InputStream inputStream2 = httpConn2.openInputStream();//getInputStream();
                DataInputStream dataInputStream2 = new DataInputStream(inputStream2);

                // Interpret the response obtained 
                dataInputStream2.readShort();
                dataInputStream2.readByte();

                int code = dataInputStream2.readInt();
                //Dialog.alert(code+"");

                if (code == 0) {
                    latitude= dataInputStream2.readInt() / 1000000D;
                    longitude=dataInputStream2.readInt() / 1000000D;

                    //Dialog.alert(latitude+"-----"+longitude);  

                    dataInputStream2.readInt();
                    dataInputStream2.readInt();
                    dataInputStream2.readUTF();

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error obtaining Cell Id ");
                }
                outputStream2.close();
                inputStream2.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

The WriteDataGoogleMaps function is given below-

```
 private static void WriteDataGoogleMaps(OutputStream out, int cellID, int lac)
throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(out);
    dataOutputStream.writeShort(21);
    dataOutputStream.writeLong(0);
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("en");
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Android");
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("1.0");
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Web");
    dataOutputStream.writeByte(27);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(3);
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("");
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(cellID);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(lac);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0);
    dataOutputStream.flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Blackb Pearl. Its working with your code. Just one more question. When I install my app, a dialog pops up that asks for user permission to access Radio information. I added ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_LOCATION_DATA but it still pops up the same dialog. How can I prevent the dialog from poping up? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: change ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_LOCATION_DATA  to ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_LOCATION_API

Comment: Its still showing the same dialog: "The Application is attempting to access radio information that may identify your location". What should I do?